Christoph Benzmüller and Gödel's ontological proof?
Are there any notable mathematical or logical issues within Christoph Benzmüller and Bruno Woltzenlogel-Paleo formalized Gödel's ontological proof (pdf) that has been identified by the community?

2022 Benzmüller paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.06264.

@JoelDavidHamkins Thank you :^).

No, it has been formalised in a proof assistant, and the formalisation is small enough you can fit it on a page (actually it's only 43 lines of Isabelle code), and so peruse it for yourself. By the way, Benzmüller's paper in Joel's comment is published as https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-031-42127-3_19 But the result doesn't say what one can imagine it says, as discussed on the Wikipedia page.

The links that Joel Hamkins so kindly provided should appear in the question.

Note that the version linked in Joel's comment is not the result referred to by the OP, but a streamlined version that proves the same result by an argument that is simpler and more transparent than Gödel's (i.e. it doesn't formalise Gödel's proof blow-by-blow)
